# How to port arduino code into non-ATMEL device?

Tags: arduino, iot, esp8266

I am fairly new to microcontrollers and programming them, etc.

I have been working with Arduino uno and ESP8266 12E module. I have been successful in developing a prototype for IOT Automaion.

Now I want to integrate a new chip (Microcontroller + WiFi) by High Flying. Its called the HF SIP120.

But I have never worked with anything other than arduino. I am clueless on how to go ahead to use the new SIP120.

It might sound a dumb Question. But I am a complete Amateur. Any kind of help is much appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: Step 1: Write a core for the platform.

Comment: The device I want to use says it supports AT- firmware. So by writing a core for the platform, you mean I will have to convert the entire Arduino Code into a code that uses AT commands?

Comment: Start with getting the device SDK. Then you possibly find related examples in it.

Comment: What OS running on your Microcontroller?